# Can an OBD2 device be used to limit vehicle speed?

Tags: obd-ii, obd

Is it possible? And if so, which OBD2 device can do it?

Comment: A "normal" code reader / clearer probably not.... Even a dealer level device probably not.

Comment: @SolarMike a quick look online give a wide list of cruise control devices : https://www.speedlimiter.net/ https://www.speedlimiter.net/cruise-control.html https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s95HZbjf52Q https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xmTlHsXZgs which only does this this However their quality or maybe even their safety practices of manufacturers is questionable.